# Our DC Motor gives high Current at relatively low load. Why?

Tags: dc-motor

I am a Drilling Manager working on a Drilling Rig. Currently we are facing a problem that's been baffling us for sometime.

Through my extensive experience and we have data to prove it. A DC motor can easily PULL load upto 150 Tons at 750amps. However, now it can hardly pull 100 tons at 1100 Amps at the same exact resistance

So what could be the problem?. And yes we have change the DC motors twice, now we have a brand new one, but exact the same issue?.

Comment: It isn't clear from description if it's a problem that showed up after using the motor for some time. Also you should better specify the construction of the DC motor. One may suspect you are running it at an improper field operating point.

Comment: Are you running at a lower rotation speed then normal (RPMs)?

Comment: Its definetly the issue is not with the motor. As I mentioned, I have change three DC motors of the same model. So I am confident the Motor has no issue. Also I have compared both readings at the exact RPM. But for some reason now I cannot pull pass 100 tons and already I am experience high current, which was not the case before as I mention above

Comment: Ok, but a motor does not exist in a vacuum, and we still would need more info to be able to help you. How are you powering it? What are the motor specifications (power, voltage/current ratings)? What is the motor architecture (is it a universal motor? how are the coils arranged?).

Comment: Talk with your boss and get a guy out who knows what he's doing to diagnose the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: What are the RPM? Or is the motor stalled, thus as max torque? Has the transmission (gearing system) changed?

Comment: Its all about energy, it is usually conserved. That means if you put electricity into the motor, from an energy perspective it will be burned up as heat in the motor, or converted to magnetic energy to move the motor. Figure out which one it is, your torque load is probably higher, and not constant or your calculating it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is some serious current.
I would suggest checking your connections are all good, clean and tight.
Take resistance readings across the joints or through the run of the cable, even 1 Ohme across a joint would cause problems at this current.
Look for HOT joints.
Have the cables been changed?
Maybe they have melted or damaged.

Your statement "A DC motor can easily PULL load upto 150 Tons at 750amps" is not true, it depends on the motor, a 6V model railway motor wont do 750 amps.